# C# socket server refuses the connection from a python client

Tags: python, c#, sockets

I am just getting started with C# , and I was trying to make a socket server that can receive connections from python client, however server keep on refusing to connect.

**Here is server code :**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

// State object for reading client data asynchronously  
public class StateObject
{
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;

    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    // Thread signal.  
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public AsynchronousSocketListener()
    {
    }

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
   
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 45545);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.  
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.  
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket.
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read
            // more data.  
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the
                // client. Display it on the console.  
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                    content.Length, content);
                // Echo the data back to the client.  
                Send(handler, content);
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.  
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        StartListening();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**and here is Python Client :**

```
import socket
import time
from datetime import datetime
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
clientSocket.connect(('localhost',45545));
time.sleep(10000);
```

initially the python client was supposed to send some data to the server but then i noticed that connection isnt being established , so i removed the part where its sending the data and only using the code that is responsible for establishing the connection.

**Here is what is am receiving at the python client side :**

[image]

I am not sure whats going on , but is it possible that server is refusing the connection because the client is not a C# client and is a python client ?

Comment: The client (python) and the server can't be connected to the same IP addrress.  So normally the listener uses IP.Address.Any.  Also .AddressList[0] is usually these days an IPV6 so you need to use .AddressList[1] which is IPV4.

Answer (score 0):

it was an embarrassing mistake , i assumed that the server is listning to the localhost but server was listening on  `192.168.x.x`
so Python client `clientSocket.connect(("192.168.x.x",xxxxx));` succeeded in making connection